# Wrong Suggestion from ReSharper for Binding Path in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, path, resharper

I get a misleading suggestion from ReSharper (6.1) to replace the property name 'Content' inside my binding path with a type from System.Windows.Interop. As my SO reputation is too low I can't show a screenshot, so I try to make you a "drawing" of the popped up ReSharper suggestion:

```
<DataTemplate>                        |(?) System.Windows.Interop.Content? (Alt+Enter)
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content.Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I can ignore the suggestion and move on but once in a while I will fall victim to the suggestion.
Or I can rename my property to something else, but that is my very last option.
Has anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because ReSharper could not manage to resolve the Content property and found the type System.Windows.Interop.Content, and tried to guess if you wanted to use that.

In principle, it shouldn't be that intrusive...

Thanks for the feedback. We'll discuss with the team.

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior with every part of a binding path that is reported with the statement "Cannot resolve symbol 'FooBar'". Just create a class with the name of the reported part and ReSharper will suggest that you use the type.